# Run working wine instance from another harddrive

Tags: wine

I have a working wine installation on old harddrive. There
is root directory (/) on one partition and `/home/username`
directory on another partition.

I installed wine on new harddrive and when I run it it gives
me some OLE error.

How can I run the old version of wine, so that I mount the
old partitions and run the version that is on the old harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

Likely this problem relates to your WINE requiring libraries which also live under your /home/username file hierarchy.

If I required WINE for a project, I'd likely us Ubuntu + find a PPA which packaged the most current version of WINE. This way I could just install WINE anywhere + have it work.

That said, you can likely **fix up your Library path** as follows.

```
# Find all libraries in your WINE executable
ldd path-to-your-handrolled-username-installed-WINE

# record all directories reported
# note: also run ldd on any non-system installed libraries
# add list of libraries to your ~/.bashrc or equivalent,
# listing every non standard path
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path[:path...]
```

Setting this in ~/.bashrc will work + may crash other programs.

Better to create a script... maybe... wine_start, which export LD_LIBRARY_PATH + then executes WINE. This way you can collect all these library path settings into a script, rather than polluting your default runtime environment.

Comment: you are assuming things. The OP did not give enough data; we do not know neither his OS (could be MacOS) nor wether it was manually installled or a package, or if it lives at /home, /usr/local/bin or wherever-

Comment: I mounted the partition with wine. $ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/tb and then cd /media/tb/usr/bin.
ldd ./wine shows linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7782000)
 libwine.so.1 => /media/tb/usr/bin/./../lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwine.so.1 (0xb763c000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7607000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7450000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb744b000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80029000)

Comment: What I would like to do is. Always run wine from /media/tb/usr/bin/wine and use the config files as follows:
mount /dev/sdb5 /media/tb2.
cd /media/tb2/username/.wine . I would like to connect /media/tb/usr/bin/wine with /media/tb2/username/.wine directory